# OpenType CMAP format that supports mapping an array of characters to a glyph id? [migrate?]

Tags: fonts, opentype, character-set

**I am unsure if this is in the correct community.**

I'm writing a [Scala wrapper](https://github.com/TsundereBug/Scolor) to [the OpenType font format](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/otff.htm), and while trying to find an encoding ID for [the CMAP table](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/cmap.htm) that maps an array or set of characters, I see mapping 1 or 2 characters to a glyph ID but not a sequence of characters to a glyph [like Google's material icon font](https://material.io/icons/) can.

Is there an encoding ID for the CMAP table in the OpenType specification that allows me to map a sequence of characters to a glyph ID? Can I emulate this using a UVS encoding type? UTF-32 is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this data lies in [the GSUB table](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/gsub.htm). This is so that individual glyphs can still be rendered, while providing the opportunity for glyph combination.